# Probability of $X_1 \geq X_2$

Tags: self-study, random-variable, geometric-distribution

> Suppose $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent geometric random variables with parameter $p$. What is the probability that $X_1 \geq X_2$?

I am confused about this question because we aren't told anything about $X_1$ and $X_2$ other than they are geometric. Wouldn't this be $50\%$ because $X_1$ and $X_2$ can be anything in the range?

EDIT: New attempt

$P(X1 ≥ X2) = P(X1 > X2) + P(X1 = X2)$

$P(X1 = X2)$ = $\sum_{x}$ $(1-p)^{x-1}p(1-p)^{x-1}p$ = $\frac{p}{2-p}$

$P(X1 > X2)$ =  $P(X1 < X2)$ and $P(X1 < X2) + P(X1 > X2) + P(X1 = X2) = 1$

Therefore, $P(X1 > X2)$ = $\frac{1-P(X1 = X2)}{2}$ = $\frac{1-p}{2-p}$
 Adding $P(X1 = X2)=\frac{p}{2-p}$ to that , I get $P(X1 ≥ X2)$ = $\frac{1}{2-p}$

Is this correct?

Comment: Please add the 'self-study' tag.

Comment: Actually because `X1` and `X2` are discrete variables the equality makes things a bit less obvious.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can't be $50\%$ because $P(X_1=X_2)>0$

One approach:

Consider the three events $P(X_1>X_2), P(X_2>X_1)$ and $P(X_1=X_2)$, which partition the sample space.

There's an obvious connection between the first two. Write an expression for the third and simplify. Hence solve the question.

Comment: I edited, my post with my new answer. Could you take a look and see if it's correct?

Comment: Yes, your answers look correct. An alternative method (using a similar idea) would be to note that $P(X_1\geq X_2)=\frac12 + \frac12 P(X_1=X_2)$ (again, exploiting the symmetry/exchangeability of $X_1$ and $X_2$).

Answer (score 6):

Your answer, following Glen's suggestion, is correct. Another, less elegant, way is just to condition:

\begin{align}
  \Pr\{X_1\geq X_2\} &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr\{X_1\geq X_2\mid X_2=k\} \Pr\{X_2=k\} \\ &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{\ell=k}^\infty \Pr\{X_1=\ell\}\Pr\{X_2=k\}.
\end{align}

This will give you the same $1/(2-p)$, after handling the two geometric series. Glen's way is better.

Comment: note - your way is better for applying to new problems I think. Because it is based on first principles. The trick/intuiton from glen_b's answer usually comes *after* the problem has been solved your way

Comment: @probabilityislogic I share your enthusiasm for derivations from "first principles." 
 However, to a modern mathematician, looking for and exploiting symmetry is even more fundamental than the first principles (definitions) to which you refer: we might call it a *metaprinciple* of mathematics.  It's much more than a mere "trick."